# Obtain information on encrypted android card image

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, android

For several days now I have tried to recover the key for an encrypted android-container (android_expand, used as internal storage) without success. As all kinds of stuff of the past years is on that card. As all other attempts failed I will try to break it with brute-force.

Yet I struggle to get the information on how the partition is actually encrypted. I took a dd image of the whole SD-card and try now to figure out what's the best way to try brute-force using bruteforce-luks as apparently it's an encrypted LUKS-container.

How do I obtain more information on how the container is encrypted? And what would be the best way to decrypt it?

```
Disk ANDRO.bin - 63 GB / 59 GiB - CHS 7765 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 P Unknown                     2048   are   34815      32768 [android_meta]
 2 P Unknown                    34816  124735454  124700639 [android_expand]
```

Comment: You could try but it will probably fails. AES 128 which was in use ... will be very hard (almost impossible) to decipher.

Comment: Seems there are some known flaws about Android full encryption. Could that relate to the Internal Memory too? https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/07/01/turns_out_breaking_android_fulldisk_encryption_is_easy_with_the_right_code/

Answer (score 4):

Android uses a 128-bit key to encrypt its adoptable SD cards. It's pseudorandom, not derived from the user's password. Brute-forcing a pseudorandom 128-bit key is hopeless.

If you somehow had access to the key (it's saved in /data/misc/vold/ on the device), it's easy to use that to decrypt it. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage explains how you do that. But if you don't have access to that key, you have no way to even hope to decrypt it.

Comment: The key was deleted for some reason. I only have the name of the keyfile and some files in the bench-folder I'm able to restore